# Ubuntu Moblin:There is no log in button on my web services! Please help!

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

Problem is there are username and password fields but no log in button so i can confirm, when i try pressing enter nothing happens anyway. Any solution to this matter?

Comment: To help you and to answer your question we need at least some details on your Ubuntu version, application in question, and screen size.

Answer (score 1):

Have you entered in your information and attempted to press <kbd>Enter</kbd>?